# android.media.audiofx : Querying for available audio algorithms in HW

Tags: java, android

For some reason these function calls all return false on a KitKat device with a Qualcomm MSM8960 chipset:

```
boolean bAec = AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable();
boolean bAgc = AutomaticGainControl.isAvailable();
boolean bNs = NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable();
```

The chipset supports all of the above algorithms, so I'm wondering why I'm getting FALSE as return value?